# How to program the actions of share activity on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

How to program the action share activity when click on facebook to share the content.

[image]

I create the content facebook but i dont know how indicate when click on facebook share.

[image]

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Compartir");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Descargar");
startActivity(sendIntent);

private void shareFacebook(){

    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
            .setContentDescription(
                    "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
         .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
            .setImageUrl(...)
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("text/plain");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://developers.facebook.com/android");
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share"));
```